# How to import a pure Groovy Script to a Spock Test without Classes

Tags: unit-testing, gradle, groovy, spock

I have the following Groovy Script:

**TheScript.groovy**

```
package groovy

def sayHi = "hi"
```

And the test spec for it. **Note:** *This is just a theory not a serious approach by me. Just want to show you what I tried to achieve.*

**TheScriptSpec**

```
import spock.lang.Specification
import spock.lang.Unroll
import groovy.TheScript // what to do instead?

class TheScriptTest extends Specification {
    def "Test One"() {
        expect:
        sayHi() == "hi" // sayHi() does not exist - how to call the field?
    }
}
```

The error thrown tell me surely that there is nothing defined for **TheScriptTest.sayHi()** - and that's just fine. I understand that error

Comment: Use the GroovyShell to parse the script and then use it in your test. Won't work exactly as you show, but should be close enough.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your issue is you are defining a variable in your script "def sayHi" then in your test you are calling it as though it is a method.

```
def sayHi(){ return "hi" }
```

note: I believe the word 'return' is not necessary in groovy.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create script `sayHi.groovy`

```
package groovy

//
def call() {
 return "hi"
}
```

In Groovy we can add a method named call to the script and then invoke the method without using the name call. We would simply just type the parentheses and optional arguments on an object instance. Groovy calls this the call operator: ()

```
import spock.lang.Specification
import spock.lang.Unroll
import groovy.TheScript

class TheScriptTest extends Specification {
    def "Test One"() {
        expect:
        sayHi() == "hi"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get an instance of your script `TheScript.groovy` using **new**, and then call its `run()` method.

Your test should look like:

```
import spock.lang.Specification
import spock.lang.Unroll
import groovy.TheScript

class TheScriptTest extends Specification {
    def "Test One"() {
        expect:
        new TheScript().run() == "hi"
    }
}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: This answer is nearly working. the test-script must have same package like script under test, the import is not working for me.

Comment: Iam sry nor import, nor package statement is necessary. And also Jacoco will work fine, if you forget about them. Recognize, that any folder structure isnt discussed here.